# Filebench Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a shell script that is able to run the Filebench benchmark utility. Filebench allows you perform a variety of FileIO tests to ascertain performance. To run it manually you first type >sudo filebench - this then gives you the following prompt >filebench> - you then type >load  - and finally the duration of the test >run 60. I have been attempting to do this with the following script but it just hangs at the filebench> prompt waiting for more input.

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo filebench 
load filemicro_seqread 
run 60 

echo "Starting test" $(date +"%H:%M:%S") >> seqRead.txt
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but will this work?:

```
sudo filebench << SCRIPT >> seqRead.txt
load
run 60
SCRIPT
```

read more about "here documents" [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)